# Setcontent / Selecting on dates

Tags: twig, where-clause, bolt-cms

> Bolt's docs [say](https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching#selecting-dates) what you can use several ‘shortcuts’ for
>   selecting records with dates in the past or future. And "Internally,
>   Bolt uses the strtotime() funtion for this, so we refer to its manual
>   page for details."

So, i trying use `date_modify()` in `setcontent = 'something' where {}` but it doesn't work.

Here what i tried to do:

```
{% setcontent = 'showtimes' where
   { datefield: '>tomorrow && <"tomorrow"|day_modify("+1 day")' }
 %}
```

And can i use variable in this condition instead `"tomorrow"|day_modify("+1 day")`?

Could you tell me please, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do is not as straightforward.

You cannot modify the shortcuts that way. The "shortcut" tomorrow is only working inside the setcontent, so the part where you try to modify it with a twig filter "tomorrow"|day_modify("+1 day") will not work.

You could try the following, but I'm not sure if that works:

```
{% setcontent = 'showtimes' where { datefield: '>tomorrow && <+2 days'  
%}
```

Otherwise you will need to prepare the date format before you call the setcontent, and then append it to the parameter string:

```
{% set day_after_tomorrow = "+2 days"|date("Y-m-d") %}
{% setcontent = 'showtimes' where { datefield: '>tomorrow && <' ~ day_after_tomorrow %}
```